# merge with lambda formula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

how can I combine the unique ones according to their ID numbers in shifts as follows and how can I collect the rightmost values ​​as unique. Using the lambda formula.

The table link is below. I have data on page TEST1 and I want to sort by page TEST2. using lambda formula.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVM6n.png) and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpzzs.png)

and i want like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0wYj.png) and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVWuB.png)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wMzXjcELKdg-j1o5kEI_mL6d9Qr-6QM8-IMDUz4yFBo/edit?usp=sharing

google sheets combine

Comment: 1, Why are some instances of `H` (*TEST1*) changing to `H.T` (*TEST2*) 2, How did you get the value of `28.5` in **Cell_AJ4** (*TEST2*)

Comment: can you look again all value will H.T my fault.
i will write test2 page manually but i need formula

Comment: and 28.5 will 18.5 sorry because summation

Comment: People lose interest in your question if your example is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=byrow(unique(TEST1!A3:C),lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,{Σ,bycol(TEST1!D:AI,lambda(Λ,ifna(+filter(Λ,TEST1!B:B=index(Σ,,2),Λ<>"")))),bycol(TEST1!AJ:AT,lambda(Ξ,sumif(TEST1!B:B,index(Σ,,2),Ξ)))})))
```

[image]

Comment: This post is hidden. It was deleted 10 mins ago by greg-449, mozway, esqew.
TEST1 page with the importrange formula I pull data from another file, the data I pull comes to the TEST1 page, but the data I pull brings the values of the formulated data from another file, so it converts date data such as 45292 45293 45294 45295 45295 45296 45297 into numbers. It gives this error when the extracted data should be empty. How can I fix it?